# Dynamically check old and new values in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Sql Server 2008 R2

I am developing a syncing process that needs to build update/insert/delete statements from a trigger. I'm not worried about the inserts or deletes, I have a question on the updates.

What I'd like/want to do is compare the old and new values of each column that are generated during the update process. ONLY the columns that are changed, do I want to include them in my sync script.

Well, after some digging and testing, my question really boils down to this: I'm trying to execute this statement and it says it doesn't recognize 'inserted'. Is there a different way to do this?

```
Set @sqlText = 'Insert Into ##changedColumns (ColumnName, NewValue, PrimaryKey) Select ''' + @column + ''', i.' + @column + ', i.' + @primaryKeyColumn + ' From inserted i Inner Join deleted d On d.' + @primaryKeyColumn + ' = i.' + @primaryKeyColumn + ' Where i.' + @column + ' <> d.' + @column

Exec(@sqlText)
```

Comment: Why not just use Sync Framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902853.aspx

Comment: @Blam need to sync to an iOS application that can be in a disconnected state

Comment: I think you should post the actual problem.  One option is to use a rowversion.  Change the design such that the table only has a rowID fieldID, and fieldValue columns.  I know that seems radical but right now you have a data design that is not designed for column row level syncing.

Comment: @Blam are you talking about my sync table, or my source table that contains the trigger? If you're talking about the source table, I'm not able to alter the structure/schema as it's owned by a different team...

Comment: @Blam in regards to "but right now you have a data design that is not designed for column row level syncing" and if you were talking about changing my source table, then I think it's the end of my question since I can't modify my source table. I'd have to just hard-code all of the columns, and/or generate my sync script for ALL columns in the table.

Comment: I was talking about the source tables.  Even if you get it working you would have cursor involved in every trigger.  A hard coded trigger is going to be more efficient.   Could you add rowversion column?

Comment: The INSERTED and DELETED virtual tables are not accessible in the scope of the dynamic SQL.  In order to use them in the dynamic SQL you would need to insert them into a temp table first, and then use them inside of your EXEC.

Comment: @user17594 you are correct, I was literally coming back to this just now so that I could update (and ask) if that was the way to go. I was thinking of doing "Select * Into #changedRow From Inserted"

Comment: I really wish I could try and get this working, but architect thinks it would impact performance to much so we are going the route of hard-coding all of the columns for each of the tables' triggers. Oh well, I learned something, even though I'm not going to be able to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is the route you took I will post my comment as an answer

Even if you get it working you would have a cursor involved in every trigger.
A hard coded trigger is going to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an earlier edit of the question, I think something like this may be what you are looking for:

```
-- sample table
CREATE TABLE [tableA]
(
  TableAId int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Column1 int not null,
  Column2 int null,
  Column3 varchar(50) null
)
GO
-- procedure to create sync trigger on target table
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateSyncTrigger]
    @table_name NVARCHAR(128)
AS

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 'CREATE TRIGGER [mySyncTrigger_' + @table_name + '] ON ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + ' 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
' + (
SELECT
    CHAR(10) + 'IF UPDATE(' + QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]) + ')
    INSERT INTO ##changedColumns([ColumnName], [NewValue], [PrimaryKey])
    SELECT ''' + [COLUMN_NAME] + ''', I.' + QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]) + ', I.' + QUOTENAME([pk_column_name]) + '
    FROM INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN DELETED D
    ON      I.' + QUOTENAME([pk_column_name]) + ' = D.' + QUOTENAME([pk_column_name]) + '
    WHERE I.' + QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]) + ' != D.' + QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]) + CHAR(10)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS X
CROSS JOIN ( -- get primary key col
    SELECT 
        D.[name] [table_name],
        C.[name] [pk_column_name]
    FROM sys.indexes A
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns B
    ON      A.[object_id] = B.[object_id]
        AND A.[index_id] = B.[index_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.columns C
    ON      B.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
        AND B.[column_id] = C.[column_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.tables D
    ON      C.[object_id] = D.[object_id]
    WHERE   A.[is_primary_key] = 1 
        AND D.[name] = @table_name
) Y
WHERE   X.[table_name] = @table_name
    AND X.[COLUMN_NAME] != Y.[pk_column_name]
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)');

-- create trigger on target table
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
GO
-- create sample trigger
EXECUTE [CreateSyncTrigger] 'TableA'

GO
-- sample trigger output
CREATE TRIGGER [mySyncTrigger_TableA] 
ON [tableA]
AFTER UPDATE
AS

IF UPDATE ([Column1])
    INSERT INTO ##changedColumns([ColumnName], [NewValue], [PrimaryKey])
    SELECT 'Column1', I.[Column1], I.[TableAId]
    FROM INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN DELETED D
    ON I.[Column1] != D.[Column1]
    ...

GO
```

Running the procedure will create the desired trigger for every non-primary-key column for the table name provided.